# Apply filter on joined tables with MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, filter

I store some data in MySQL and want to filter out rows that match a given criteria.

Sounds easy, but it is not since there are some join criteria involved.

I do have the following tables:

```
items : id, ...
genres: id, name:varchar, item_id
```

Each item has multiple genres.

The query should filter **out** items if at least one genre does match a given genre name (or a set of names).

For example:

```
Item with id 1 has 3 genres
  - genre name = 'foo'
  - genre name = 'bar'
  - genre name = 'baz'
```

Item 1 may not be part of the result set if the given genre name is 'bar', ['bar', 'baz', 'xyz'], etc.

I tried to left join the genres on the items and applied a WHERE statement with "genres.name NOT IN (?)". ? is the given set of genre names.

This (of course) only works for items with exactly one genre. The same could be achieved by multiple WHERE conditions: WHERE name <> 'a' AND name <> 'b' ...

Any ideas how to get this query done properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please give a sample query, explain what it does, then explain what you want it to do differently?

Comment: I don't understand the tables yet... so you have an `items` table and a `genres` table. Why does the latter table have an `item_id` column? I expected to see a many-to-many association table that links items with genres.

Comment: Why you want to filter out items if at least one genre does match a given genre name?Where as in first line of your problem you wrote the opposite of it.

Comment: To @RaviJain's point, your example doesn't match your desired result description above. According to your description, Item 1 _would_ be part of the resultset since it includes `bar`, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery.
Example:

```
SELECT id 
FROM   items i
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   genres g
                   WHERE  g.`name` = 'bar' 
                   AND    i.id = g.item_id);
```

A correlated subquery differs from other subqueries in that it references the outer query.
Correlated subqueries are run for each row projected/selected by the outer query.

Comment: I guess this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you bernie!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this ([see sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0070c/32)):

```
select i.name as item, g.name as genre
from items as i
left join genres as g
  on i.id = g.item_id 
where i.id not in
      (select distinct g2.item_id from genres as g2
       where FIND_IN_SET(g2.name,'foo,bar'));
```

And this way it works if you want to check against multiple genre names.

Comment: Thanks! Also have a look at bernies approach. Solves the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well hopefully I understand what you are asking for and I think MySQL and T-SQL will be similar in this respect.  These are the sample tables I assumed you were using from your example.

```
Table1
ID  NAME
1   Item 1
2   Item 2
3   Item 3
4   Item 4
5   Item 5
6   Item 6

Table2
ID  NAME    ITEM_ID
1   Genre 1   1
2   Genre 2   1
3   Genre 3   1
4   Genre 1   2
5   Genre 2   2
6   Genre 3   2
7   Genre 1   3
8   Genre 2   3
9   Genre 3   3
10  Genre 1   4
```

Here is the SQL to filter **out** items if they match one of your criteria.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.id = b.item_id
AND b.name NOT IN ('Genre 1', 'Genre 2')
```

Results returned from above query on sample tables.

```
ID  NAME    ID_1    NAME_1  ITEM_ID
1   Item 1    3 Genre 3   1
2   Item 2    6 Genre 3   2
3   Item 3    9 Genre 3   3
```

You could also filter out against the genre_id (table2.id) instead.  If you plan to use a sub-query instead of hard coded values then you should switch the "NOT IN" to a "NOT EXISTS" and re-write the "AND" portion accordingly as "NOT IN" does not like null values.

This query also assumes that each "Item" has at least 1 "Genre."  I am sure you can play with it if you want all "Items" excluding the ones that match your criteria.

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work, because one has to provide all genre names of an item to get the item out of the list. At least one matching genre name should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from items i where not exists 
(select '' from genres gen where gen.item_id = i.id and gen.name in ('foo','pop') )
```

A shorter ans simpler query.
The inner query checks genre name in the keywords list , if the no row is returned then the current row of outer query is selected.
Verify the output
[at here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f8d6/2).

Thanks to [Kyra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310613/kyra)
,i borrowed his schema from sql fiddle.